# No Sound other then Drumming!

Tags: 13.04, sound, login

Its been almost 47 days that I am using Ubuntu 13.04, and today I came to know that Ubuntu has its tones for different actions like for

1. ShutDown
2. Login
3. Logout
4. New Device Inserted

but after booting it only plays drumming tone, I think that’s for notifying system is ready but what about others. How can I enable them , I want all the tones present in

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
```

in action. Only system-ready.ogg is working.
[image: files under stereo]

I have tried

```
sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/* /usr/share/sounds/
```

but even it doesn’t work out.

Comment: Where exactly did you learn that ubuntu has sounds other than the drumming that comes up when lightdm starts?

Comment: see drumming is for notifying system is ready , but there are other .ogg files too for login and all, i want to enable them so that it will login sound as windows and shutdown sound at shutdown like windows.